# Websocket задержка пересылки пакетов

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

Приветствую!
Между клиентом и сервером через WebSocket как в синхронном, так и асинхронном режиме периодически возникает задержка пересылки пакетов в несколько секунд.

Проявляется даже в локальной сети, где проблем с транспортом никаких нет.
Что можете посоветовать?

Что посмотреть, чем мониторить?

Answer (score 0):

@Fotomizer WebSocket всегда в асинхронном режиме. никаких задержек нет. если есть в локальной сети  - это к админам этой сети.